# Curl Request in "Tastypie" returns 401 unauthorized error

Tags: php, python, django, curl, tastypie

I am using Django-Tastypie 0.11.1 and I am trying to create a user in the auth_user model of Django(v1.6) from a third party website ( Regular API Call ).

**Resource :**

```
class CreateMasterResource(ModelResource):

    def hydrate(self, bundle):

        # Logic to Validate username and Password

        bundle.data["password"] = make_password(bundle.data["password"])

        return bundle

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.using("master").all()
        resource_name = 'create_master'
        default_format = 'application/json'
        list_allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
        serializer = Serializer()
        # authentication = MultiAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication(), SessionAuthentication())
        # authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True
```

**Issue:**
I am trying to send a CURL request from a WP site. And I have made sure to pass the API key Authorization Apikey : in headers and as well as in "GET" Params http://xyz.example.com:8000/master/api/v1/create_master/?username=johndoe&api_key=S4M4L34PIK3Y:

**The request hits the Django Server and returns a 401 error code. No error message. When using var_dump() on the curl response it returns "".**

**CURL Request sent from WP site:**

```
    $data = array(
        "first_name" => $order->billing_first_name,
        "last_name" => $order->billing_last_name,
        "email" => $order->billing_email,
        "password" => $password, 
    );

    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                
    $ch = curl_init('http://xyz.example.com:8000/master/api/v1/create_master/');          
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(    
        'Authorization: ApiKey abc@xyz.com:',                             
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                             
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($result);
```

**Debugging so far :**

1. Was using MultiAuthentication(). Both session and API. Removed the whole class, was using DjangoAuthorization() removed it as well for debug purposes.
2. Tried using ipdb in dehydrate of the resource class. Couldnt reach that point .. it clearly means something like error occurs before reaching the resource.
3. **Note : My email is my username. The User  and API key that I'm using has a superuser status set to True and staff status set to True as well.**

Kindly let me know what i'm missing and I am aware that i should not be removing the auth classes. It was removed for debugging purposes.

Comment: Hi can you add to your Meta `authorization = Authorization()` and `authentication = Authentication()` and check does it help. Default authorization is read-only http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#readonlyauthorization.

Comment: Thanks man.. Works like a charm. authentication = Authentication() seems to have done the trick. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can answer your own question below. It may be useful for others.